Manipulating little-o notation (particularly $n^{o(1)}$)
I'm confused about what little-o notation means in different contexts. In particular, I'm confused about what $n^{o(1)}$ would mean.
I know that the definition of little-o says that $f(n)$ is $o(1)$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n) = 0$.
But, then I don't understand what $f(n) = n^{o(1)}$ means. I would want to say something like $f(n) = n^{o(1)}$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = n^0 = 1$, but I'm sure this is not the correct interpretation. Could someone please explain how this notation works when it is used as an exponent?

$o(g(n))$ is always a set, including in the case $g=1$. When a set appears in a context that calls for a function, it's the set of outcomes you can get from its functions, in this case ${n^f|f\in o(1)}$.

$f(n)=n^{o(1)}$ simply means: $f(n)=n^{g(n)}$ for some $g$ such that $g(n)=o(1)$.
Equivalently: $$\frac{\log f(n)}{\log n}=o(1).$$

$n^{o(1)}$ is more or less a shortcut for: "let $u$ be a sequence verifying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{u_n} = 0$, consider $n^{u_n}$".
